# Django REST how to set throttle period to allow one request in 10 minutes?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, throttling

Documentation says that period should be one of: `('s', 'sec', 'm', 'min', 'h', 'hour', 'd', 'day')`. I am curious if I can set period to something like `1/10min`?

Comment: But the title says, once in ten minutes. So that means `10min` right?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, I need to block users from sending more that 1 request per ten minutes

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L52) and [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/) you cannot do this 'out of the box'. But I do see the possibility described to make your own [custom throttle](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#custom-throttles) based on one of the existing one's:

```
from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle


class AnonTenPerTenMinutesThrottle(AnonRateThrottle):
    def parse_rate(self, rate):
        """
        Given the request rate string, return a two tuple of:
        <allowed number of requests>, <period of time in seconds>

        So we always return a rate for 10 request per 10 minutes.

        Args:
            string: rate to be parsed, which we ignore.

        Returns:
            tuple:  <allowed number of requests>, <period of time in seconds>
        """
        return (10, 600)
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically what XY said is true but it might not work because you still have to put the rate like this:

```py
from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle

class AnonTenPerTenMinutesThrottle(AnonRateThrottle):
    

    rate = '1/s' # <<<<< This line is very important
    # You just can enter any rate you want it will directly be overwritten by parse_rate
    

    def parse_rate(self, rate):
        """
        Given the request rate string, return a two tuple of:
        <allowed number of requests>, <period of time in seconds>

        So we always return a rate for 10 request per 10 minutes.

        Args:
            string: rate to be parsed, which we ignore.

        Returns:
            tuple:  <allowed number of requests>, <period of time in seconds>
        """
        return (10, 600) # 10 Requests per 600 seconds (10 minutes)
```