# How to limit form submit request in Django app

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to limit submitting request for visitors(anonymous) in my django app.

Suppose 10 or 50 limits per day/month. If they try to search more than my given limit I want to show a message "you have reached your daily or monthly limit!"

How can I do this?

Here is views:

```
def homeview(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and 'text1' in request.POST:
        text1 = request.POST.get('text1')
        text2 = request.POST.get('text2')
        data = my_custom_function(text1, text2)
        context = {'data': data}
    else:
        context = {}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

here is form in template:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="form-control m-3 w-50 mx-auto" type="text" name="text1" id="text1" placeholder="">
    <input class="form-control m-3 w-50 mx-auto" type="text" name="text2" id="text2" placeholder="">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-3" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [throttling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/) from the [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). But there is no throttle rate for a month out of the box. Maybe you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/50371440/4151233 to create a specific class.

Otherwise, I recommend writing your own implementation. This should be adapted to the requirements with questions such as:

- Are my users authenticated when making the requests?
- How fast should it be and how much load is expected?
- Is a standard DB query acceptable or does it need to be implemented
  with the cache framework?

Comment: Does throttling work on my app? Or Is It for API?

Comment: If you will use Django REST framework, you can use throttling with one of the generic views it provides. Otherwise, you will write your own implementation and hook it into your view.